# Downloading videos from youtube in asp.net , missing streamp map

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube.net-api

I'm creating an small application in asp.net c# for download videos from youtube, I'm using the youDownloaderExtension and I have an issue when trying to download some particular videos, I had searched on the web with no success , I'm thinking this may be a problem with the copyright or video format, can somenone tell me how can i workaround this problem. I got the following exception.

Missing stream map.
Paremeter Name : videoInfo

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to download YouTube videos from the YouTube servers to your own to host without authorization (there is a copyright in place). If this is what you are after then I suggest you ask a shadier community for help.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the answer, but what is a shadier community?

Comment: Perhaps one that wears an eye-patch?